# Autenticação no Laravel

Tags: laravel

Usando o Laravel, o que eu posso fazer para que apenas usuários autenticados possam fazer cadastros de novos usuários?
Com isso, a página de registro de usuários seria acessada apenas por usuários autenticados. Nas configurações padrão do Laravel o registro é feito livremente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou considerar que você esteja utilizando a versão `5.3` do Laravel. A forma mais simples é atribuir o middleware `Auth` no construtor da sua classe `\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController`, dessa forma:

```
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth'); // anteriormente definida como guest.
}
```

Se você conferir a sua lista de rotas através do comando `php artisan route:list`, vai verificar que a partir de agora as rotas de registro (as duas últimas da imagem a seguir) estão protegidas pelo middleware de usuários autênticados (auth).

[image: Rotas de um projeto novo com Laravel versão 5.3.]
*Figura 1: Rotas de registro protegidas pelo middleware de usuários autênticados (auth).*

Se você estiver utilizando uma versão anterior do Laravel, por esta ser uma pergunta de nível muito baixo, você pode conferir a página da documentação oficial. Por exemplo, na [página de controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#controller-middleware) da versão 5.2, existe um tópico específico para a atribuição de múltiplos middlewares nas rotas e no construtor de um controller.

Comment: Obrigado, Rafael! Me salvou. rsrs' +1